# remove php short tags from html source

Tags: php, regex, php-shorttags

I am parse some html code with curl. some site's html source like:

```
<div id="content">
    some words
</div>
<?    
    $box_social['dimensioni']="80";
        $box_vota=array();
    $box_vota["novideo"]='';
    $box_vota["nofoto"]='';
    $box_vota["id_articolo"]='1003691';
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/incs/box_social.php");    
?>
<div id="footer">
   some words
</div>
```

How to remove php short tags from html source? I need

```
<div id="content">
    some words
</div>
<div id="footer">
   some words
</div>
```

And I use `preg_replace('/<\?(.*?)\?>/','',$html);`, but the php short tag part still there.

Comment: You mention that you're parsing it with curl? Is the stuff you're parsing delivered through a webserver then? It will not work this way.

Comment: if you're getting PHP code via the URL then there is something *seriously* broken with the server or the server config at the other end. If this is a third party site, then you should notify them immeditately, because this is likely to be a security problem for them as well. You shouldn't need to filter this stuff out, because they shouldn't be letting their server output it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches your case:

```
$html = htmlspecialchars(preg_replace('/<\?([\w\W]*)\?>/','',$html));
$html = htmlspecialchars(preg_replace('/<\?(.*)\?>/s','',$html));
```

This also matches if more than one block of PHP is there:

```
$html = htmlspecialchars(preg_replace('/<\?([^\?>]*)\?>/','',$html));
```

FROM [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>       If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are
>   excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A
>   negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character,
>   independent of the setting of this modifier.